# Opening .avhdx file from Hyper V virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v

I have .vhdx and .avhdx files. First one is 4KB, 2nd 70GB, so its safe to assume that everything what i need is in 2nd file. How can i open it? I need to get one file which is saved on virtual machine hard drive.

Answer (score 3):

U need merge .avhdx with destinationpath .vhdx  with this command

tHIS IS AN EXAMPLE WITH VM = sirha82022 u need change text to ur VM name

1. Open Powershell with administrator
2. Put dir to VM direction example

   **dir E:\VMACHINES2022\Virtual Hard Disks>**
3. put this command and apply ur VM name on this

**Merge-VHD -Path ".\NAMEA_VHDX.avhdx" -DestinationPath ".\NAME_VM.avhd"**

Example:

**Merge-VHD -Path ".\sirha82022_7ECC6258-4ACF-43F6-8BB0-38572F29FA7C.avhdx" -DestinationPath ".\sirha82022.vhdx"**.

4. Mount the .vhdx resultant

Comment: Why all these capitals and bold characters?

Comment: Thank you! Very competent and useful.

Answer (score 0):

> How can i open it?

Windows 10 has native support to mount VHDX files.  In order to mount a VHDX, right-click on the file, and select **Mount**

> 1. Right click or press and hold on the .vhd or .vhdx file, and click/tap on Mount.
>
> [image]

Source: [Directly Mount VHD or VHDX file](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/61391-mount-unmount-vhd-vhdx-file-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: Cannot mount AVHDX file.

Comment: @CorporalGirrafe - That would due to the fact, `AVHDX` isn't the correct file, and isn't the virtual HDD.

Comment: Yes, avhdx is basically a checkpoint file and you should work with them differently.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/checkpoints